# Data entry summon data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to build a MASTER sheet that saves NON CHANGEABLE data like the following:

```
Course ID - Course Units - Course Title - CRN - ACCT
```

these data will be permanent and non changeable no matter what.

However I need to create another table that has a data entry interface so when the user enters the `Course ID` it will summon the other data and insert it,
then the user will fill other changeable data, like course time, date, etc.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, questions about specific web sites/services are off-topic here. You might be able to get help at [webapps.se]. (For more information on our scope, see the [help/on-topic].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following:

1. Create Sheet 1, containing master data
2. Create Sheet 2, which users can edit. This draws from Sheet 1 useing `VLOOKUP`.
3. Lock Sheet 1, so only Sheet 2 can be edited by users.

*Caveat: Note that Sheet 1 will be locked, but still visible to users.*

### 1. Create master data sheet

In Sheet 1, enter master data like below.

[image]

### 2. Create user edit sheet

In Sheet 2, create headings for data you want to display.

[image]

Still in Sheet 2, select the cell in which you want the user to toggle their choice. Make this a dropdown field based on your master data:

[image]

[image]

This will give you a nice dropdown like below:

[image]

Then, use `VLOOKUP` to get the relevant values from Sheet 1 to display on Sheet 2. I've also used `IFERROR` so that when the selection in `B4` is blank, `B5` is also blank (rather than displaying an error).

[image]

### 3. Protect master data sheet

Lastly, use *Data > Protected Sheets and Ranges* to restrict which sheets or ranges users are able to edit.

*Caveat: Note that Sheet 1 will be locked, but still visible to users. Perhaps using "hide rows" in Sheet 1 (as well as protecting the sheet) will do the trick, but I haven't been able to test this idea.*

[image]

Comment: Life Saver! Can't say enough. Thank you million times.